# Check for Uniqueness in Multiple Columns in Django

Tags: django

My User Models Contains columns (email and alternate_email).
Note: Both are unique fields

Requirement is 
For any user email and alternate_email should be unique, i.e.

Let Say UserA registered with (email = a@b.com and alternate_email = b@c.com). Now it should not allow any other user to have (email = b@c.com and alternate_email = a@b.com). Or No other user should have either of a@b.com & b@c.com in email or alternate_email field.

There are multiple ways to achieve this

1. Check if email is already there in any of the two columns and register User only if email is not present.
2. Try to insert and handle if it fails because of Integrity check
3. Keep emails in some cache

The above solutions does not seem to be efficient. What is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: you can use unique_together

Answer (score 0):

you can use `unique_together` or `UniqueConstraint` for newer versions of django

```
UniqueConstraint(fields=['first_email', 'second_email'], name='unique_email')
```

Comment: This wont work. because as per requirement (first_email, second_email) and (second_email, first_email) should not be allowed. But UniqueConstraint will allow this

Answer (score 0):

In your model, override the save method and call `self.clean()`.
Also you have mentioned that `email` and `alternate_email` are unique field, so you can check if the email or alternate_email exists.

```py
from django.db.models import Q  

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.clean()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def clean(self):
    super().clean()

    if User.objects.filter(
       Q(alternate_email = self.email) | Q(email = self.alternate_email)
        ).exists():
            # raise Error or process ?
```

This query will return true if any of the case exists.

IntegrityError will be raised if you are saving duplicate value in `email` or `alernate_email` column.
Not the best solution I guess, but will get the job done.